# Undefined variable in laravel 8 - Trying to fetch <select> list from DataBase

Tags: laravel

I am trying to fetch a list from the database into a `<select>` for the form.
I have a controller with classes **(index, getLocations, create, store, edit, update, destroy)**

```
public function getLocations($locationList)
    {
        $locationList = Locations::select('id', 'locationName')->get();
        return view('pages.dataEntry.reports.reports', compact('locationList'));
    }
```

`getLocation` has its own Model:

```
class Locations extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'kaec_locations';
}
```

and I get undefined variable `$locationList is undefined`

```
<select class="form-select" name="caseLocation">
                        <option value="none" selected disabled>Select Location</option>
                        @foreach ($locationList as $item)
                            <option value="{{ $item->id }}"> {{ $item->locationName }} </option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
```

- Is this a good practice? to have a separate Model for locations?
- How come the variable is undefined? Should it be included in the route?

```
Route::controller(ReportController::class)->group(function () {
            Route::get('reports', 'getLocations');
            Route::get('reports', 'index')->name('reports.index'); // Index page (DataTable)
            Route::get('reports/create', 'create')->name('reports.create'); // The form for adding new records
            Route::post('reports/create', 'store')->name('reports.store'); // Add new to DB
            Route::get('reports/edit/{report}', 'edit')->name('reports.edit'); // The form for editing records
            Route::put('reports/edit/{report}', 'update')->name('reports.update'); // Update record to DB
            Route::get('reports/{report}', 'destroy')->name('reports.destroy'); // Delete from DB
        });
```

Comment: It seems correct. Did you check you have refer to the correct blade file?

Comment: The blade for the form is `_addForm` which I changed in the controller from `reports`. However still same error

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I do not need to make a function for this. I already have function for adding new data `create()`. The `Create` refers to the blade file of the form I want to display that `<select>`

So I just removed the `getLocations()` and added the code to `create()`

```
/**
    ** Add new Record Page.
    **/
    public function create()
    {
        $locationList = Locations::all();
        return view('pages.dataEntry.reports._addForm', compact('locationList'));
    }
```